# How to Restore or backup messages from Rabbit mq queue

Tags: rabbitmq

In Production Rabbit MQ queue is having around 50000 messages so want o take backup of the queue and want to push new messages

Comment: Take a look at https://www.rabbitmq.com/backup.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'Dead Letter Exchanges' and a lazy queue (dead queue). In this implementation you can set your desired message TTL for main queue in which you are publishing your messages. When this message TTL will expire, it publishes messages to 'Dead Letter Exchanges' and then by routing key it will be moved to lazy queue. In this fashion your main queue will never stuck or get filled.
Ref - [enter link description here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html)